# Existence of the word "analkoholisch" (antialkoholisch)

Tags: word-usage, etymology

I'm wondering if I can use the word "analkoholisch" for things like water, coke etc. 
This word sounds quite familiar to me, but I know that the correct term would be "antialkoholisch" or "alkoholfrei".

Wikipedia says that "analkoholisch" is an old expression, but I can't find something useful on the Web about this wird.

Comment: Could you mean *analkoholisch*? This is indeed a dated expression for antialkoholisch. Where does Wikipedia mention *analkokolisch* (with k)?

Comment: sorry, a triple typo caused by smartphone :-) it remembered the first typo and autocorrected it the other two times. I mean analkoholisch

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a scientific settings we do sometimes use the prefixes **an-, ana-, a-** in the meaning of not-containing: *anorganisch, anaerob, asozial, anachronistisch,... etc.*.

This was not the case for substances not containing alcohol. The expression *analkoholisch* was never used to any significant extent. This makes me believe that proposing this to be an out-dated adjective is plain wrong.

The appropriate German expression for anything not containing alcohol is built using the suffix **-frei**: **[alkoholfrei](http://www.dwds.de/?view=1&qu=alkoholfrei)**.

Sometimes the adverb *antialkoholisch* can be seen. This however is a semantically wrong usage of the prefix **anti-** (*agains*) probably coming from the noun *Antialkoholiker*, i.e. a person who refuses to drink alcohol. A beverage can not be this, nor is there any anti-dote to alcohol which would make a prefix *anti-* valid.

Comment: as I did research there is also no entry in the German Duden, so maybe this word is not used for a long long time or it never existed. So it's just existing in a chemical /scientific way?

Comment: @Fraggles In corpora there's no entry for "analkoholisch", one (incorrect) use of "antialkoholisch", one use of "alkohollos" (where you usually would use "ohne Alkohol") and 89 uses of "alkoholfrei". The tendency is clear, I guess.

Comment: Die Vorsilbe "anti" ist für Personen, die keinen Alkohol trinken, genauso falsch. Es gibt Gruppen, die gegen Alkohol zu Felde ziehen, und konsequenterweise dann auch keinen Alkohol trinken (vielleicht), soweit ich weiß die Heilsarmee. Die kann man vielleicht Antialkoholiker nennen.

Answer (score 4):

#### Präfix an:

Das Präfix *an* stammt aus dem Griechischen [(siehe punkt [3])](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/an-#Pr.C3.A4fix) von *ἀ-* --> *"nicht", "un-"*.

#### Präfix anti:

Auch das Präfix *anti* stammt aus dem Griechischen, hat [aber eine andere Bedeutung](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/anti-):
*ἀντι-* --> *"gegen". (Nebenbei bemerkt ist Antialkoholiker dort als Beispiel vermerkt)

#### Vergleich:

> an-alkoholisch --> nicht /un- alkoholisch
> anti-alkoholisch --> gegen-alkoholisch

Damit ergeben sich zwei Bedeutungen, die nicht übereinstimmen.

Siehe:

**Antialkoholiker**: Jemand, der sich gegen den Verzehr von Alkohol ausspricht.
**an-alkoholisches Getränk**: Getränk ohne Alkohol.
**anti-alkoholisches Getränk**: Getränk, das Gegenstück zu Alkohol ist, bzw. die Auswirkungen von Alkohol mindert oder negiert.

Comment: Du hast zwar theoretisch Recht, aber der Kampf ist verloren. Wir sprechen selbstverständlich von antialkoholischen Getränken, das sind solche, die einfach keinen Alkohol enthalten, und es gibt Antialkoholiker die einfach selbst keinen Alkohol konsumieren, ohne deswegen gleiche ihre Umgebung entsprechen missionieren zu müssen. Mein ÖWB definiert Antialkoholiker als *jmd. der aus Prinzip keinen Alkohol trinkt*. Mit der Definition kann ich leben.

Answer (score 3):

Chemically it might be correct. If you wanted to talk to people **"nicht-alkoholisch"** would be the best expression.

Comment: +1, especially when you pronounce it like anal-koholisch.

Comment: You are not incorrect, but I think "alkoholfrei" is more common.